# What are valid reordering for Java synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

Many people asked similar questions like this, but none of their answers satisfied me.
The only two reordering rules that I am *very* sure of are as
    follows:

1. Operations inside the synchronized block(or just call it
   critical section) are **allowed** to be reordered, as long as it confirms to the as-if-serial semantics.
2. Operations(including both
           reads and writes) are *disallowed* to be moved(reordered) out of the critical section.

However, for those operations that are before or after the synchronized block, can they be moved into the critical section? For this problem, I found some contrary. For example, the [cookbook](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) said that the compiler will insert some barriers after the MonitorEnter and before the MonitorExit:

```
MonitorEnter
 (any other needed instructions go here )
[LoadLoad] <===MB1:Inserted memory barrier
[LoadStore] <===MB2:Inserted memory barrier
(Begin of critical section)

....
(end of critical section)
[LoadStore] <===MB3:Inserted memory barrier
[StoreStore] <===MB4:Inserted memory barrier
 (any other needed instructions go here )
MonitorExit
```

According to be above placement made by the compiler and given below pseudo code:

```
  Load a;
  Load b;
  Store 1;
  Store 2;
  MonitorEnter
     (any other needed instructions go here )
    [LoadLoad] <===MB1
    [LoadStore] <===MB2
    (Begin of critical section)

    ....
    (end of critical section)
    [LoadStore]  <===MB3
    [StoreStore]  <===MB4
     (any other needed instructions go here )
    MonitorExit
  Store 3;
  Store 4;
  Load c;
  Load d;
```

According to the cookbook and reordering prevention rules enforced by such XY(X is Load or Store,Y is  Load or Store) memory barriers, it seems to me that valid/invalid reordering are as below:

Understanding 1: Any stores(Store 3 and Store 4 here) after the MonitorExit can *NOT* be moved up  before MB3 and MB4, because of the existence of a LoadStore(MB3) followed by a StoreStore(MB4). That's to say stores after the MonitorExit cannot be moved into critical section. However, it *can* be moved up after MB4,namely the bracket area.

Understanding 2:Any loads(Load a and Load b here) before the MonitorEnter can *NOT* be moved down after MB2 and MB1, because of the existence of a LoadLoad(MB1) followed by a LoadLoad(MB2).That's to say loads before the MonitorEnter cannot be moved into critical sention. However, it *can* be moved down  after MB2,namely the bracket area.

Understanding 3:Any loads(Load c and Load d here) after the MonitorExit *can* be moved up before the MonitorExit, including the critical section and the  bracket area, but it cannot exceed the MonitorEnter.

Understanding 4: Any stores(Store 1 and Store 2 here) before the MonitorEnter *can* be moved down after the MonitorEnter, including the critical section and the  bracket area, but it cannot exceed the MonitorExit.

However, all the above understanding or claim see to be contrary to what Jeremy Manson said in his [blog](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html), where he claimed that give below code:

```
x = 1;//Store
synchronized(o) {
z = z + 1;
}
y = 1//Store
```

Reordering that produce below code *is* allowed:

```
synchronized(o){
y = 1;//I added this comment:Store moved inside the critical section
z = z + 1;
x = 1;//I added this comment:Store moved inside the critical section
}
```

According to Understanding 1, "y=1" cannot be moved up inside the critical section,
So I just was confused, which one is correct and complete?

Comment: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fi/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering do not care about memory barriers. Even if the compiler always inserts the strongest memory barrier between any two instructions, these reordering are still permitted regardless.

Now, given a sequence of instructions, possibly after being reordered from the the original sequence, the compiler needs to insert proper memory barriers between some instructions.

For example, given an original sequence of instructions

```
volatile store x
normal   store y
```

It does not need memory barrier between the two instructions.

However, the compiler may choose to reorder it to

```
normal   store y
volatile store x
```

then a StoreStore barrier is needed between the two instructions. The CPU only has a "store" instruction, no concept of normal/volatile store. And the CPU  may have out-of-order stores. It is the Java semantics that requires that another CPU must not observe the effect of `store x` before the effect of volatile `store y`; so a StoreStore is used to tell the CPU to store them in order.

(If the compiler is smart enough, it'll remember that the original program does not require the ordering of `y->x`, therefore this barrier is not actually needed. But let's say the compiler isn't that smart.)

---

Roach Motel model --

The point of JMM is to establish some (partial) orders among instructions on different threads, so that effects of reads/writes can be defined. In the following example,

```
thread 1             thread 2

  a1                   a2
  |
 }b1       ----->      b2{
                       |
  c1                   c2
```

a synchronization order `b1->b2` is established, which could be `volatile store -> volatile load`, or `monitor exit -> monitor enter`. This connects `a1->b1->b2->c2` in happens-before order.

Since we need to guarantee the ordering of `a1->c2`, `a1` must not be reordered with `b1`, and `c2` must not be reordered with `b2`; that is, a roach cannot "check out".

On the other hand, JMM wants to be as weak as possible; it says nothing about the effects between `c1` and `a2,b2,c2`; therefore, `c1` can be freely reordered with `b1`. Similarly, `a2` can be reordered with `b2`. That is, a roach can "check in".

Comment: Even if "the compiler is smart enough", according to my understanding, the compiler still needs to insert a StoreStore in your example, because it should prevent the processor from reordering between instructions that precedes the volatile store and the volatile store itself so as to enforce the semantics of a volatile store.

Comment: Thanks @bayou.io for your detailed explanation! My understanding is that, to sum it up, for reads and writes that precedes the MonitorEnter or followed the MonitorExit, they *can* be moved(reordered) into the critical section during compilation(JIT compilation).However, once the compilation is done, the moved reads/writes cannot be moved out by processor, due to the memory barriers inserted by the compiler which will be regarded by processor, am I right?

Comment: Suppose the original program is `normal store A; volatile store B`. JMM semantics is that, after another thread sees the effect of B, then it should also see the effect of A. Now, it's JVM's job to implement that semantics on a particular CPU architecture. A CPU may perform writes out-of-order by default; but it'll also support a barrier instruction to disable that. So on that CPU, JVM first will keep the order of A and B, i.e., no reordering by JVM; then JVM will insert StoreStore between A and B, i.e. no reordering by CPU.

Comment: Notice in the cookbook how similar the reordering table and the barrier table are. If instructions `P;Q` should not be reordered per JMM, the 1st table will forbid reordering by JVM, and the 2nd table will forbid reordering  by CPU. The combined effect is that `P;Q` don't appear to be reordered when observed by other CPUs.